# How to add more then 4 items to uitabbar in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I want to add more then 4 `items` to `tabbar`. But it shows me `more button`. I don't want more button instated of it I want two more item.When I am adding 5th item it shows me error `index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]`
Code is Like This

```
LoginScreen *login=[[LoginScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginScreen" bundle:nil ];

MenuScreen *menu =[[MenuScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuScreen" bundle:nil];

EmergencyScreen *emergency =[[EmergencyScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"EmergencyScreen" bundle:nil ];

NewsScreen *NewS = [[NewsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsScreen" bundle:nil];

CalenderScreen *calender=[[CalenderScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalenderScreen" bundle:nil ];

NotificationScreen *notification =[[NotificationScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationScreen" bundle:nil];

HelpScreen *help =[[HelpScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpScreen" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];

UINavigationController *nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:emergency];

UINavigationController *nav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:NewS];

UINavigationController *nav4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:calender];

UINavigationController *nav5=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:notification];

UINavigationController *nav6=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:help];

nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:login ];
tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

tab.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nav6, nil];

UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabItem setTitle:@"Menu"];

UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1];
[tabItem1 setTitle:@"Emergency"];

UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2];
[tabItem2 setTitle:@"News"];

UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3];
[tabItem3 setTitle:@"Calender"];

UITabBarItem *tabItem4 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:4];
[tabItem4 setTitle:@"Notification"];

UITabBarItem *tabItem5 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:5];
[tabItem5 setTitle:@"Help"];
```

It is not Showing me Notification and Help.
Please Help me..

Comment: You can add as many items as you wish in UITabBarController but after four all the items will appear in more tab. Only one solution is that you can create custom tabbar controller with scrollview.

Comment: how to create custom tabbar with scrollview

Comment: or how to add that two item in more

Comment: HERE ARE LOTS OF CUSTOM TABBAR  : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tabbar use any of that suitable for your requirement

Comment: here is links   https://github.com/valitovaza/scrollableTabbar

https://github.com/vermontlawyer/JFATabBarController

Comment: How can I add it I just need a simple code

Comment: I need to add two item instated of more.

Comment: can I add Item at the click of more.